# View incorectly positioned after keyboard shown

Tags: android, android-view

I make a custom view which height should be always 40 dp.
Works fine in normal cases, but is shifted down, when  soft keyboard is shown.
On second screenshow it is visible, that red button is shifted downwards, but there is no code for that.

Issue is present on android >=5, versions 4.x.x does not have this issue.
How to get rid of it?
In layout

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
            >
          <ua.in.femid.view.widget.MyTextView
              android:id="@+id/btn_deny"
              android:layout_width="0dip"
              android:layout_weight="210"
              android:layout_height="40dip"
              android:background="@drawable/bg_primary_stroke"
              android:textColor="@color/request_deny"
              android:text="@string/dr_back"
              android:gravity="center"
              style="@style/roboto_medium"
              android:textAllCaps="true"
              android:textSize="12dip"
              android:clickable="true"
              />
          <Space
              android:layout_width="16dip"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              />
          <ua.in.femid.view.widget.RoundButtonView
              android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
              android:layout_width="0dip"
              android:layout_weight="350"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:color_end="@color/error_tapped"
              app:color_start="@color/error_red_light"
              android:text="@string/dr_confirm"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              style="@style/roboto_medium"
              android:textColor="@color/white"
              android:textAllCaps="true"
              android:textSize="12dip"
              android:clickable="true"
              />
        </LinearLayout>
```

View itself

```
public class RoundButtonView extends Button {
  private OnClickListener listener;
  Paint mBgPaint;
  private static final long ANIMATION_DURATION_MS = 250l;

  RectF rectBG = new RectF();
  private int minHeight = 0;
  private float mPercent = 0f;
  Matrix shaderMatrix;
  int colorStart;
  int colorEnd;
  int cornerSize;

  public RoundButtonView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public RoundButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
  }

  public RoundButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
  }

  private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    shaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    minHeight = (int) (40 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    cornerSize = (int) (20 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mBgPaint = new Paint();
    mBgPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mBgPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundButtonView);
    ColorStateList startList = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.RoundButtonView_color_start);
    if (startList != null) {
      colorStart = startList.getDefaultColor();
    } else {
      colorStart = Color.BLUE;
    }
    ColorStateList endList = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.RoundButtonView_color_end);
    if (endList != null) {
      colorEnd = endList.getDefaultColor();
    } else {
      colorEnd = colorStart;
    }
    if (a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RoundButtonView_square, false)) {
      cornerSize = 0;
    }
    a.recycle();
  }

  @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int h = minHeight;
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, h);
    rectBG.set(0, 0, MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), h);
    mBgPaint.setShader(
        new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, rectBG.bottom, colorStart, colorEnd, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));

  }

  public void setColorStart(int colorRes) {
    if (colorEnd != colorStart) {
      colorStart = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), colorRes);
    } else {
      colorStart = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), colorRes);
      colorEnd = colorStart;
    }
    mBgPaint.setShader(
        new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, rectBG.bottom, colorStart, colorEnd, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    invalidate();
  }

  @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    shaderMatrix.setTranslate(0, -rectBG.bottom * mPercent);
    mBgPaint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(shaderMatrix);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectBG, cornerSize, cornerSize, mBgPaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }

  ValueAnimator animator;

  @Override public void setOnClickListener(final OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    RoundButtonView.this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            if (event.getX() > 0 && event.getY() > 0 && event.getX() < rectBG.right
                && event.getY() < rectBG.bottom) {
              long prevDuration = ANIMATION_DURATION_MS;
              if (animator != null && animator.isRunning()) {
                prevDuration = animator.getDuration();
                animator.cancel();
              }
              invalidate();
              animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(mPercent, 0);
              animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
              animator.setDuration(prevDuration);

              animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                  setPercent((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }
              });
              animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                  invalidate();
                  if (v != null) onClickListener.onClick(v);
                }

                @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                  invalidate();
                }

                @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
              });
              animator.start();
            } else {
              long prevDuration = ANIMATION_DURATION_MS;
              if (animator != null && animator.isRunning()) {
                prevDuration = animator.getDuration();
                animator.cancel();
              }
              invalidate();

              animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(mPercent, 0);
              animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
              animator.setDuration(prevDuration);

              animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                  setPercent((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }
              });
              animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                  invalidate();
                }

                @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                  invalidate();
                }

                @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
              });
              animator.start();
            }

            break;
          }
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            long prevDuration = ANIMATION_DURATION_MS;
            if (animator != null && animator.isRunning()) {
              prevDuration = animator.getDuration();
              animator.cancel();
            }
            invalidate();
            animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(mPercent, 1);
            animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            animator.setDuration(prevDuration);

            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
              @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                setPercent((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
              }
            });
            animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
              @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
              }

              @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                invalidate();
              }

              @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                invalidate();
              }

              @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

              }
            });
            animator.start();
          }
          break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            break;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

  private void setPercent(float percent) {
    mPercent = percent;
    invalidate();
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add `android:layout_gravity="center"` to your RoundButtonView?